# How to select from joined table if there is no pair in itin MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have table `product` (1910 lines) with `id` and `name` fields. 
Then I have table `image` (1000 lines) with `productId` and `value` fields.

How can I list all the products with their images? If I use left join then I'll get only 1000 lines without products those don't have images.

Comment: You want only product with images or all product with/without images???
Your question is knida confused

Answer (score 0):

This schould do your work:

```
Select p.name, i.value from product as p LEFT OUTER JOIN image as i on p.id = i.productID
```

You will geht everything from table1 and the images from table 2

Answer (score 0):

If you want all related record use left join

```
 select a.id, a.name, b.value 
 from product as a 
 left join image as b on a.id = b.prodcutId
```

if you want only the image matching product use inner join

```
 select a.id, a.name, b.value 
 from product as a 
 inner join image as b on a.id = b.prodcutId
```